# What does the $# construct mean in bash?

Tags: bash, scripting, shell, syntax

I see

```
foo() {
if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    return 0 
fi

...

}
```

What exactly is it comparing by using $# as it does there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$#` represents the *number of command line arguments* passed to the script.

```
sh-3.2$ cat a.sh
echo $#  #print the number of cmd line args.
sh-3.2$ ./a.sh
0
sh-3.2$ ./a.sh foo
1
sh-3.2$ ./a.sh foo bar
2
sh-3.2$ ./a.sh foo bar baz
3
```

When used inside a function(as in your case) it represents the number of arguments passed to the function:

```
sh-3.2$ cat a.sh
foo() {
        echo $# #print the number of arguments passed to the function.
}
foo 1
foo 1 2
foo 1 2 3

sh-3.2$ ./a.sh
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 3):

`$#` is the number of arguments passed to the script. See the **Special Parameters** subsection of the **PARAMETERS** section of the `bash(1)` man page for the full list.

Answer (score 2):

`$#` = **Number of arguments passed to the function**.

in your code, the function will return 0 if the function is not called with **one parameter at least**.